# Time-optimization of Java source code (CodeChef CubeCakes)

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime

I am working on the `CodeChef` `"Cube Cakes"` practice problem here:([See docs](http://www.codechef.com/problems/CUBE)).  The response from `CodeChef` is that the runtime is too long.  Any suggestions about time-optimization?

My code is here:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CubeCakes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Comparison[] comparisons = new Comparison[scan.nextInt()];
        for (int i = 0; i < comparisons.length; i++)
            comparisons[i] = new Comparison(scan.nextInt(), scan.nextDouble(), scan.next(), scan.next());
        scan.close();       
        for (Comparison e : comparisons) System.out.println(e.compare());
    }
}

class Comparison {
    int N;
    double minPercentEqual;
    char[][][] cube1, cube2;
    double[][][] sim;

    public Comparison(int sideLength, double minPercentEqual, String cube1, String cube2) {
        this.N = sideLength;
        this.minPercentEqual = minPercentEqual / 100;   
        this.cube1 = fillCube(cube1);
        this.cube2 = fillCube(cube2);
        this.sim = new double[N][N][N];
    } public char[][][] fillCube(String cubeString) {
        char[][][] cube = new char[N][N][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
                for (int k = 0; k < N; k++) cube[i][j][k] = cubeString.charAt(i*N*N + j*N + k);
            }
        } return cube;
    }

    public String compare() {
        String retVal = "-1";
        for (int length = 1; length <= N; length++) {
            int similarSubcubes = 0;
            int maxpow = 1;
            if (length > 1) maxpow = (int) Math.pow(2, (int) (Math.log(length - 1) / Math.log(2)));
            for (int i = 0; i+length <= N; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j+length <= N; j++) {
                    for (int k = 0; k+length <= N; k++) if (isSimilarSubcube(i, j, k, length, maxpow)) similarSubcubes++;
                }
            } if (similarSubcubes > 0) retVal = length + " " + similarSubcubes;
        } return retVal;
    }

    public boolean isSimilarSubcube(int x, int y, int z, int length, int maxpow) {
        //if (x + length > N || y + length > N || z + length > N) return false;
        double similarity = 0;
        int a = x; int b = y; int c = z;
        while (maxpow > 0) {
            for (int i = a; i < x+length; i += maxpow) {
                for (int j = b; j < y+length; j += maxpow) {
                    for (int k = c; k < z+length; k += maxpow) {
                        if (length == 1 && cube1[i][j][k] == cube2[i][j][k]) sim[i][j][k] = 1;
                        similarity += sim[i][j][k];
                    }
                }
            } a += maxpow; b += maxpow; c += maxpow;
            maxpow /= 2;
        } if (Math.pow(2, length) % 1 == 0) sim[x][y][z] = similarity;
        return (similarity / Math.pow(length, 3)) >= minPercentEqual;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider posting this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: A brute force solution won't work. Hint: if you know for each i, j, k how many common characters are in the subcubes `[0..i][0..j][0..k]`, how could you find the number of common characters in `[i1..i2][j1..j2][k1..k2]`?

Comment: @sebii, I did this at the base-2 scale, see method isSimilarSubcube().

Comment: @lreeder Usually when one gets a time limit exceeded on these competitions, it's fundamentally a wrong approach, not something that can be fixed with some minor improvements, so [so] would be more appropriate than [codereview.se].

Comment: @La-comadreja You should summarize the problem statement in the question itself, don't just link to it.

Comment: @Dukeling, the problem statement is quite long and complicated and could obscure the question.  Basically, I'm looking for suggestions about simple things in the code that could be made faster.

Comment: As I noted in my comment to lreeder, simple improvements are unlikely to help, but if that's all you're after, it is indeed probably better suited for [codereview.se] (subject to their guidelines).